# comparing growth of nth derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt {{x^2} + {c^2}}$ and $(n-1)!$

Tags: calculus

I want to compare the growth of nth derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt {{x^2} + {c^2}}$ and $(n-1)!$ as n goes to infinity. by using mathematica, numerically,
I know that when $c$ is greater than 1, $\frac{{{f^n}(x)}}{{(n - 1)!}}\xrightarrow{{n \to \infty }}0$ but I can't prove it analitically.

Comment: Are you allowed to help yourself with Taylor expansion or binomial formula?

Comment: yes. but notice in my problem x is in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your statement

$$\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{(n-1)!}1^{n-1} \rightarrow 0$$
Introduce new variable $g=f'$:
$$\frac{g^{(n-1)}(x)}{(n-1)!}1^{n-1} \rightarrow 0$$
But this is equivalent to the statement, that the Taylor expansion of $g$ around $x$, evaluated at $(x+1)$, has terms decreasing to zero.

But for Taylor series, we actually know more: it is convergent within its radius of convergence. Now all you need to prove is that radius of convergence is at least 1 no matter where your starting point is. Additionally, differentiation or integration do not change the radius of convergence, so the proof for $g$ also proves the same statement for $f$.

The radius of convergence for Taylor series equals the distance to the first singularity in the complex plane: usually a pole (e.g. $1/(1+z)$ has a pole at $z=-1$), or a branch point ($\log z$ at $z=0$), in this case, a branch point is where the root argument is zero, so at $x=\pm i c$. The singularities are therefore on the imaginary axis: the smallest radius of convergence is, when you are closest to it, at $x=0$, where it equals $c$. For other $x$, the radius is bigger (equal to $\sqrt{c^2+x^2}$ actually).

This is not a rigorous proof, but for radius of convergence, you can use standard procedures ([browse methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) under "theoretical radius").